# advance limit results in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

i did a lots of research and still i didn't solve the problem, Hopefully some of you can help me.

i have a table `Post` and a table `Comment` with the normal relation `Post Has Many Comments`

I set up the following query for get 10 posts with the relative comments:

```
Post::with('comments')->limit(10)->get();
```

Well it work, but still is not my final result because i want limit even the comments to 5 **For each post**

So far i tried this query for limit my comments even if logically it will limit only 5 comments for all posts. In fact it does how i guessed.

```
Post::with(['comments' => function($comments){

       $comments->limit(5);

}])->limit(10)->get();
```

Maybe with eloquent this kind of query is not possible, but how can i make it work even with 2 different queries and merge the results?

Any kind of help will be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Solution is here:
http://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-n-related-models-per-parent/

Something like this:
    return $this->comments()->latest()->nPerGroup('post_id', 5);

Answer (score 0):

What I think you need to do, is limit the amount of posts in the relationship.

Something like this would do it:

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Comment')->limit(5);
}
```

Did not test this though, so it might not work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i tried to do it but limiting like that, it limit 5 comments for all posts like my query above. Do you have others ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```
    $lines = \Category::where('status', \Category::STATUS_PUBLISH)
            ->with(['firstThreeComment'])
            ->get()
            ->map(function( $category ){
                $category->firstThreeComment = $category->firstThreeComment->take(3);
                return $category;
});
```